# Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when I try to run my code

Unhandled exception at at 0x769E4598 in Testing.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0086F498.

```
int main() {
  string s = "2/1";

  int c = stoi(s.substr(s.find("/", 0), s.length() - s.find("/", 0)-1));

  cout << c;
  int pi;
  cin >> pi;
};
```

Comment: Have you inspected `s.substr(s.find("/", 0), s.length() - s.find("/", 0)-1)`?

Comment: Put the `find()` and length() results into separate variables, and check what values you get, then see what would be passed too `substr()` actually.

Comment: I did that and I should be getting s.substr(1,1), and it should not access anything outside of the string

Comment: When I run it, the substring is `/` which obviously isn't a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just read documentation more carefully. As it is states,  [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) may throw exceptions and specifically `std::invalid_argument` is thrown if no conversion could be performed.

Your code is trying to convert `"/"` to number, in that case `std::stoi` throws an exception which is not caught and thus your program is terminated.

Comment: I believe that the problem was more fundamental than that as the author's comment said he understood that the result would be s.substr(1,1). He failed to recognize that zero-based indexing is being used. The character at index 1 is '\' and not '2'.